# How to add a custom field made with acf into the excerpt while using genesis in WP

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, genesis

I want to take the text from an custom field made with acf, and put it into the excerpts shown the posts shown on the front page. I am using genesis, and I think I have to do "remove_action" and "add_action" to do this, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a filter that WordPress has called `the_excerpt`

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'your_function_name');

function your_function_name($excerpt) {
   $my_acf_field = the_field('my_acf_field');
   return $my_acf_field . ':' . $excerpt;
}
```

This would append the acf field string in the beginning of the excerpt.  If you want this to apply only on the front page, you can only add this code in your `front-page.php` file OR you can put the above code in your `functions.php` and  use the Wordpress conditional `is_front_page()` in the function code above.

(This code is untested)